# Here is challange. Spring boot JWT token. Handling exception

Tags: exception, jwt, authorization, malformedurlexception, spring-boot-security

I have API for blogging application. Working fine
When i send request for login it give me token like below

eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJuYW1lIjoibmFtZSIsImVtYWlsIjoiaG9zdDIyQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjEsInN1YiI6Imhvc3QyMkBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJpYXQiOjE2Njg0NDc5NzEsImV4cCI6MTY2ODQ2NTk3MX0.rhSK6nxgnoMg-7Urdvw2v-4Mk9U75eYxeK_FrgJgDr4

But when I send token by changing first latter of token i.e. 'e' with 'f' i should be getting error like "
"Unable to read JSON value"

I am getting exception in console - log but issue is i should be getting it in response.
***io.jsonwebtoken.MalformedJwtException: Unable to read JSON value: "alg":"HS256"}***

i tried like by creating class JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint
but it is not good idea as i am still getting exception in console log

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint, Serializable {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("---------------JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint----------------------");
        

        response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        OutputStream responseStream = response.getOutputStream();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.writeValue(responseStream, "Unable to read JSON value");
        responseStream.flush();
        
        
        //response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, authException.getStackTrace());
        

    }

    
    
}
```

i belive i have to handel exception but don't know how
The condition is exception should be handel as well as

To genrate error

1. Create simple Springboot API with JWT (Json Web Token)
   @GetMapping("/Login") - it will give token in resonce
   Method body
2. It should allow user to login and give token
3. When passing token for authentication of request replace 'e' with 'f' i.e. forst letter of token'
   @GetMapping("/Hello")
   Method body

Console logs are as

```
io.jsonwebtoken.MalformedJwtException: Unable to read JSON value: "alg":"HS256"}
at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.readValue(DefaultJwtParser.java:554) \~\[jjwt-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1\]
at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:252) \~\[jjwt-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1\]
at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:481) \~\[jjwt-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1\]
at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parseClaimsJws(DefaultJwtParser.java:541) \~\[jjwt-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1\]
at com.app.jwtApp.config.JwtTokenUtil.getAllClaimsFromToken(JwtTokenUtil.java:43) \~\[classes/:na\]
at com.app.jwtApp.config.JwtTokenUtil.getClaimFromToken(JwtTokenUtil.java:37) \~\[classes/:na\]
at com.app.jwtApp.config.JwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(JwtTokenUtil.java:28) \~\[classes/:na\]
at com.app.jwtApp.config.JwtRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtRequestFilter.java:49) \~\[classes/:na\]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) \~\[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23\]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) \~\[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4\]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) \~\[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4\]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) \~\[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4\]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) \~\[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4\]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) \~\[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4\]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) \~\[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4\]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) \~\[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23\]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) \~\[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4\]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112) \~\[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4\]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82) \~\[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4\]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) \~\[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4\]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) \~\[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4\]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) \~\[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23\]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) \~\[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4\]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) \~\[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4\]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) \~\[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23\]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) \~\[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4\]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:221) \~\[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4\]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186) \~\[spring-security-web-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4\]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354) \~\[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23\]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) \~\[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23\]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68\]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68\]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) \~\[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23\]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) \~\[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23\]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68\]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68\]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) \~\[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23\]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) \~\[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23\]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68\]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68\]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) \~\[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23\]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) \~\[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23\]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68\]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68\]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68\]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68\]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68\]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68\]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68\]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68\]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68\]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68\]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68\]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68\]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68\]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68\]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68\]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68\]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) \~\[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68\]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) \~\[na:na\]
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 127)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
at \[Source: (String)"\\u007F"alg":"HS256"}"; line: 1, column: 2\]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser.\_constructError(JsonParser.java:2391) \~\[jackson-core-2.13.4.jar:2.13.4\]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase.\_reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:735) \~\[jackson-core-2.13.4.jar:2.13.4\]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase.\_reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:659) \~\[jackson-core-2.13.4.jar:2.13.4\]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.\_handleOddValue(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:2005) \~\[jackson-core-2.13.4.jar:2.13.4\]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:802) \~\[jackson-core-2.13.4.jar:2.13.4\]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.\_initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:4761) \~\[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2\]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.\_readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4667) \~\[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2\]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3629) \~\[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2\]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3597) \~\[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2\]
at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.readValue(DefaultJwtParser.java:552) \~\[jjwt-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1\]
... 59 common frames omitted
```

I have tried by using @ExceptionHandler but not able to capture exception and handle it

Expectation is
it should send response in JSON when try to authorize user
"data":"Unable to read JSON value";
As well as Exception should be handled i.e. should be in Console log